Decomposition of tensor components in Lie Algebra Representations
I'm reading Dr. Georgi's Lie Algebras in Particle Physics and in Chapter 10 on tensor methods, he states that for the tensor product of two $\mathbf{3}$'s in $SU(3)$, the product is:
$$
[u \otimes v]^{ij} = \frac{1}{2} (u^i v^j + u^j v^i) + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{ijk} \epsilon_{klm} u^l v^m \ ,
$$
where the first term $\frac{1}{2} (u^i v^j + u^j v^i)$ transforms like a $\mathbf{6}$ and the second term $\frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{ijk} \epsilon_{klm} u^l v^m$ transforms like a $\bar{\mathbf{3}}$.
Certainly the first term transforms symmetrically and the second antisymmetrically, but why exactly is this the decomposition into irreducible components? How is the first term irreducible and why exactly do we decompose in this way?
I understand that every tensor can be symmetrized and antisymmetrized by summing over permutations of the indices. I also see how doing so is a way "decomposing" a tensor and counting the independent components shows that the totally symmetric portion has 6 independent components and the totally antisymmetric has 3 independent components.
Also, why do we need the second levi-cevita symbol to anti-symmetrize here? I'm probably not seeing something obvious here.
The other examples that are described in the chapter are:
$$
\mathbf{3} \otimes \bar{\mathbf{3}} = \mathbf{8} \oplus \mathbf{1}: \quad u^i v_j = (u^i v_j - \frac{1}{3} \delta^i_j u^k v_k) + (\frac{1}{3} \delta^i_j u^k v_k) 
$$
$$
\mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{8} = \mathbf{15} \oplus \mathbf{\bar{6}} \oplus \mathbf{3}: \quad u^i v^j_k = \frac{1}{2} (u^i v^j_k + u^jv^i_k - \frac{1}{4} \delta^i_k u^l v^j_l - \frac{1}{4} \delta^j_k u^l v^i_l) + \frac{1}{4} \epsilon^{ijl}(\epsilon_{lmn}u^mv^n_k+\epsilon_{kmn}u^mv^n_l) + \frac{1}{8}(3\delta^i_ku^lv^j_l - \delta^j_ku^lv^i_l)
$$
I'm simply not seeing what the method here is and how these are the decompositions, how to get there, and where all the traces come from. For example, in $\mathbf{3} \otimes \bar{\mathbf{3}}$, how would I just think to add $0 = \frac{1}{3} (\delta^i_j u^k v_k - \delta^i_j u^k v_k)$ and where does this $\frac{1}{3}$ come from? Also, how do I know that $\mathbf{8}$ would have one upper and lower index?

For the first decomposition, we are simply splitting $\mathbb{C}^3 \otimes \mathbb{C}^3$ into $\bigwedge^2\mathbb{C}^3$ and $S^2\mathbb{C}^3$, (antisymmetric and symmetric parts) via $v\otimes u = \frac{1}{2}(v\otimes u + u\otimes v) + \frac{1}{2}(v\otimes u - u\otimes v)$. That these are irreducible is deducible from several directions but most simply perhaps we can observe that $\bigwedge^2\mathbb{C}^3 \cong (\mathbb{C}^3)^*$ and consider the weights of $S^2\mathbb{C}^3$ (see Fulton and Harris's Representation theory page 176 for a picture of these). I think, roughly speaking, the $\epsilon^{ijk}$ is to make it antisymmetric in $i,j$ while the $\epsilon^{klm}$ is to produce an actually antisymmetric object in itself.
Then it is important to know that because $SU(3)$ is compact, the conjugate of a representation turns out to be its dual. So $\mathbf{3}$ represents $\mathbb{C}^3$ while $\bar{\mathbf{3}}$ represents $(\mathbb{C}^3)^*$. Then we should note $\mathbb{C}^3\otimes (\mathbb{C}^3)^* \cong \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}^3) = \mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{C}^3)$ via extending the identification $(v\otimes f) (u) = f(u)v$ (You should make sure you understand this identification before you try to do anything with tensors).
So your second decomposition is just the decomposition $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{C}^3) = \mathfrak{sl}(\mathbb{C}^3) \oplus \langle I \rangle$. That is into tracefree part and tracelike part. So this is just $X = (X - \frac{1}{3}\mathrm{tr}(X)I) + \frac{1}{3}\mathrm{tr}(X)I$. The $\frac{1}{3}$ comes from the fact that $\lambda I$ has trace $n\lambda$ where $n$ is the dimension ($n=3$ here). Note that it is precisely this decomposition that is telling us that the adjoint representation has  "upper and lower indices".
I don't really know what's going on with the third if I'm honest. You can deduce what the irreducible subrepresentations will be from the general theory but finding the explicit decomposition of an element is still somewhat fiddly.

Just a passerby comment, but for the third one you can use the dual of the first decomposition and the second decomposition to at least deduce $\textbf{3} \otimes \textbf{8} \cong V \oplus \bar{\textbf{6}} \oplus \textbf{3}$ for some representation $V$. What's left is to deduce $V \cong \textbf{15}$, but I too am not sure of a "natural" way like how you did with the first and second decompositions.
